# R - Obtain the connection between the numeric values and the level labels in a factor

Tags: r, r-factor

I'm struggling to find the connection between numeric (integer) values that exist in a R factor object and its level labels. I know how to define the levels and the labels. But let's assume I get an **unfamiliar** data set in which I'll find several factors (here: sex & color):

```
test <- data.frame(
                   factor(c(1,2,1,1,2,2,1),
                          levels= c(1,2),
                          labels = c("female", "male")
                          ),
                   factor(c(3,2,2,1,4,4,5),
                          levels= c(1,2,3,4,5),
                          labels= c("red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "brown")
                          )
                  )

names(test) <- c("sex", "color")
test

      sex  color
 1 female   blue
 2   male  green
 3 female  green
 4 female    red
 5   male yellow
 6   male yellow
 7 female  brown
```

I will be able to obtain the level labels by using `attributes()` and I will be able to obtain the numeric values e.g. by using `test$sex <- as.numeric(test$sex)`
But how do I know, that 1 equals female and 2 equals male? Same thing (even worse) for the colors. How do I establish the connection?

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output? A table which will tell which number represents what?

Comment: You can extract the levels using the `levels` function. And the integer values correspond to the position of the level in the levels vector. But why do you need this?

Comment: RonakShah: Yes a table would be one solution. I actually just need to know which number represents what.
@Roland: I need this because I often get unfamiliar data sets, that contain such factors. I need to know "which number represents what", in order to interpret the results. Many times however I cannot ask the creator of the data set out of various reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, the integer value simply increments along the length of the levels.  Personally, I find this easiest to visualize in a reference table.

```
test <- data.frame(
  sex = factor(c(1,2,1,1,2,2,1),
               levels= c(1,2),
               labels = c("female", "male")
  ),
  color = factor(c(3,2,2,1,4,4,5),
                levels= c(1,2,3,4,5),
                labels= c("red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "brown")
  )
)

# Make a reference table
data.frame(level = seq_along(levels(test$color)),
           label = levels(test$color))

  level  label
1     1    red
2     2  green
3     3   blue
4     4 yellow
5     5  brown
```

If you want to get the references for all of the factors in a data frame, you can vectorize the code:

```
factor_reference <- function(data)
{
  Ref <- 
    lapply(data,
           function(x)
           {
             if (is.factor(x)) data.frame(level = seq_along(levels(x)),
                                          label = levels(x))
             else NULL
           }
    )

  Ref[!vapply(Ref, is.null, logical(1))]
}

factor_reference(test)
$sex
  level  label
1     1 female
2     2   male

$color
  level  label
1     1    red
2     2  green
3     3   blue
4     4 yellow
5     5  brown
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have an output,

```
test$sex
[1] female male   female female male   male   female
Levels: female male
```

In row called "Levels" the first is 'female' and second is 'male', so 'female' is equal to 1, and 'male' is equal to 2.

If you want to change that 'male' would be 1 and 'female' would be 2, you should read about function `relevel`:

```
test$sex <- relevel(test$sex, ref = "male")
test$sex 
[1] female male   female female male   male   female
Levels: male female
```

Now 'male' in "Levels:" is the first.

Answer (score 0):

The factors are in order and when you convert to as.numeric that gives you the factor level, so you could do this:

```
factors <-data.frame(levels = as.numeric(test$color)[1:length(levels(test$color))], names = paste(levels(test$color)))

factors
```